# wxPython: Nesting GridBagSizers not spanning?

Tags: wxpython, sizer

I've g0t a GridBagSizer (folderBagSizer)within an existing GridBagSizer (sizer)... now I am trying to populate the nested sizer (folderBagSizer) with some labels.  They are showing up UNDER the sizers...?

```
# Create static box
self.sb_ExtractOptions = wx.StaticBox(panel, label="Options for Extract", 
    size=(100,100))
folderBoxSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(4, 9)
folderBoxSizer.Add(self.sb_ExtractOptions, pos=(0,0), span=(1,4), 
    flag=wx.EXPAND, border=10)

# Create the options
label_OptionsCreated = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Created:")
label_OptionsInserted = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Inserted:")
label_OptionsModified = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Modified:")

# Add them to the sizer (folderBoxSizer)
folderBoxSizer.Add(label_OptionsCreated, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|
    wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.TOP, border=3)
folderBoxSizer.Add(label_OptionsInserted, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|
    wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.TOP, border=3)
folderBoxSizer.Add(label_OptionsModified, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|
    wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.TOP, border=3)

folderBoxSizer.AddGrowableCol(2)
sizer.Add(folderBoxSizer, pos=(2, 0), span=(1,6),flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)


sizer.AddGrowableCol(2)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Sizers are basically invisible. How can you tell that the widgets are "under" the sizers? Do they jump the the right location if you resize the frame slightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, and of course, total noob logic problem.

```
    # Create static box
    self.sb_ExtractOptions = wx.StaticBox(panel, label="Options for Extract", size=(100,100))
    sbs_ExtractOptions = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sb_ExtractOptions, wx.VERTICAL)
    OptionBoxSizer = wx.GridBagSizer(4, 9)

    # Create the options
    logicList = ['<', '<=', '=', '>', '>=']

    sizerIndexX = 0

    # Created
    label_OptionsCreated = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Created:")
    combo_LogicalCreated = wx.ComboBox(panel, 1, "", (25, 25), (60, 25), logicList, wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
    combo_LogicalCreated.Select(1)
    self.tc_DaysAgoCreated = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
    label_DaysAgoCreated = wx.StaticText(panel, label="days ago")
    # Add them to the sizer (optionBoxSizer)
    OptionBoxSizer.Add(label_OptionsCreated, pos=(sizerIndexX, 0), flag=wx.ALL|
        wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, border=0)
    OptionBoxSizer.Add(combo_LogicalCreated, pos=(sizerIndexX,1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border=1)
    OptionBoxSizer.Add(self.tc_DaysAgoCreated, pos=(sizerIndexX, 2), flag=wx.ALL|
        wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border=0)
    OptionBoxSizer.Add(label_DaysAgoCreated, pos=(sizerIndexX,3), flag=wx.ALL|
        wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, border=0)

<snip>

   sbs_ExtractOptions.Add(OptionBoxSizer, flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
    sizer.Add(sbs_ExtractOptions, pos=(2, 0), span=(1,6),flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, border=10)
```

I was adding the sizer for the static box to the wrong sizer initially -- the way it needs to work is to:

1. Create the static box (self.sb_ExtractOptions)
2. Create the
   sizer that will live within it, in this case a StaticBoxSizer.
   (sbs_ExtractOptions)
3. Create the grid for my objects to layout
   within the sizer (OptionBoxSizer)
4. Create GUI elements and add
   them to OptionBoxSizer
5. Add the OptionBoxSizer to the
   StaticBoxSizer (i.e. add what you did in step 4 to step 2)
6. Add
   the StaticBoxSizer to the panel's main sizer (sizer, in this case)
7. Drink a beer, or 5.  And celebrate your new lesson like I did in
   *paying freaking attention to what you are doing!*